# ItemAdding event firing, but nothing is happening. SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I'm trying to learn Remote Event Receivers and I'm having issue getting any results from the event. The event is an `ItemAdding` event on an announcement list.

```
Public Function ProcessEvent(ByVal properties As SPRemoteEventProperties) As SPRemoteEventResult Implements IRemoteEventService.ProcessEvent
        Dim result As New SPRemoteEventResult()

       If (properties.EventType = SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding) Then
            Dim body As String = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties("Body").ToString()
            body += " something changed!"
            result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Body", body)
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
```

After adding a new item on the list it has the Modified on **date** by **appname** on behalf of **user** message, but the '**Body**' field is never changed.

Comment: Is this VB.net code? You can not run any other code than JavaScript from a SharePoint Hosted app

Comment: That code is from the remote event receiver, not the app.

Comment: If so, this is a Provider Hosted App and not a SharePoint Hosted App

Comment: Most of the app lives in sharepoint except for the event receiver. Would that not be a sharepoint hosted app? The project was created using Sharepoint Hosted as the template. I'm following a course on pluralsight. I'm just not sure why my ER will never actually do work even though the created and modified date get updated by the ER.

Comment: You should use a Provider Hosted app for this, since the Remote event receiver do need to live in a remote application (the provider hosted part)